# Continuously read Activity output without onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing

I use ZXing to read barcodes in my application. When a button is pressed, I launch the program with the following code.

```
Intent scanner = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
scanner.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
startActivityForResult(scanner, 0);
```

With this I can read one barcode. Then the reader closes and returns to my application. I use the `onActivityResult` method to retrieve the barcode. Can I somehow scan multiple barcodes without ZXing closing? I want my program to process the code whenever the scanner returns something but I don't want the scanner to close. This way I can save a lot of time when scanning a lot of barcodes. It takes a few seconds for the intent to open and close, so it's a long time in total when I have a thousand barcodes to scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this. You can use the app independently to store and save many barcodes (see "bulk mode"), and the export that to another app.